# How to avoid having two UIPopoverPresentationControllers up at same time each from UIBarButtonItem in UItoolBar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uipopover, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I'm in the process of converting an old iOS app which uses UIPopoverController to the new UIPopoverPresentationController. I have two popovers (A & B) each initiated from a click on a UIBarButtonItem (butA, butB) in a UIToolBar.  I have the popovers each displaying fine.  If I click in the main view the popovers disappear correctly.

If I press butA popover A appears.  If I then press butB nothing happens. In this case, the popover controller B was being presented from the UIBarButtonItem (butB).

If I present the popovers from a sourceRect near butA and butB, I get a slightly different result.  Click on butA and popover A appears.  Click on butB popover A disappears.  Click on butB a second time, then popover B appears.

How can I get this to work correctly, with popover A disappearing when I single click on butB?   I have tried to dismiss ViewController A as part of the butB press action, but the ViewController A object at that point is nil.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like the correct and expected behaviour. In fact the toolbar should be disabled when a popover is displayed. BTW your headline description does not match the body of your question.

Comment: What I would like is for one tap on butB to dismiss popover A and show popover B.  I was able to do this with the old UIPopoverController because it had a dismisspopover method